# Android 12 API 31, weird behavior on app starup, seeing full screen centered launcher icon instead of splash

Tags: android, android-12, android-api-31

When running few apps that I am currently working on, on latest android version (API31) saw weird behaviour, instead of seeing splash screen (how it worked on all older api's) seeing single coloured full screen background, with centered launcher icon.

Probably it does have something to do with new animations when starting the app introduced on Android 12.

How to fix it so it would work like on older api's?

[image]

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features/splash-screen  This is done for all apps when running on Android 12. You can customize it a bit, but I'm not aware of any way of disabling it.

Comment: Thanks, but we want to disable it and make it work as it was on older versions for now.

Comment: @AntonisRadz found any solution ?

Comment: no, did not managed to find any solution yet :(